# Calculate frequency in a list and output result in a specific format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list :

```
['blabla', 'tata', 'baba.com', 'fafa', 'gmail', 'momo', 'blabla', 'blabla', 'zozo', 'zozo', 'momo']
```

I would like to calculate the frequency of each word and output the sorted result like this:

blabla : 3
momo : 2
fafa : 1

I have used counter but the output isn't like i want

```
import collections
l = ['blabla', 'tata', 'baba.com', 'fafa', 'gmail', 'momo', 'blabla', 'blabla', 'zozo', 'zozo', 'momo']

c = counter=collections.Counter(l)
print(c)
```

Output :

> Counter({'blabla.com': 3, 'momo': 2 }]

How to remove the 'Counter' word from the output?

Comment: Try `print(dict(c))`

Comment: hey jpp..it's close but not exactly. I got  : {'blabla': 3, 'momo': 2 }. It is not sorted and I still have the brackets { }

Comment: Python dictionaries aren't sorted, by definition, and you wanted to remove counter, not the brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there, you use the [most_common(*[N]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method of [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this:

```
from collections import Counter
l = ['blabla', 'tata', 'baba.com', 'fafa', 'gmail', 'momo', 
     'blabla', 'blabla', 'zozo', 'zozo', 'momo']

c = Counter(l)
for item,count in c.most_common(): # tuples
    print (f"{item}: {count}") # "{}: {}".format(item,count) for lower 3.6
```

Output:

```
blabla: 3
momo: 2
zozo: 2
tata: 1
baba.com: 1
fafa: 1
gmail: 1
```

`most_common()` returns you all (or top N) results in the Counter - as `tuple(name, count)`

Comment: Fun alternative: `print(*(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in c.most_common()), sep='\n')`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list function

```
l = ['blabla', 'tata', 'baba.com', 'fafa', 'gmail', 'momo', 'blabla', 'blabla', 'zozo', 'zozo', 'momo']

print({x: l.count(x) for x in l})
```

output:
{'blabla': 3, 'momo': 2, 'zozo': 2, 'gmail': 1, 'baba.com': 1, 'fafa': 1, 'tata': 1}